# Make one button (mouse or keyboard) Do two different things

Tags: modeling, shortcut

Like, when i'm in the uv tab. I would like my mouse 4 button to mark seams. In modeling tab, i would like it to idk, add bevels or something else.

How can i make it do two separate things in different tabs ?

Comment: "Mark Seam" in 3d view and in the uv editor aren't the same command. So you can assign these shortcuts to one key without any malfunction.

Comment: I mean in the differents tabs, uv mark seam and modeling other stuff.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It works. Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blender hotkeys are devided in areas, that you can see in the **User Preferences**.

While your mouse is hovering over a certain area (for example the **3D Viewport** or the **UV Editor**), that area is the active one, and when you press a button it will use the command of that specific area.

For example, when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, if your mouse is in a **3D View** window, it will bring up the *Clear Parent* menu, while if it is in the **Text Editor** it will execute the *Run Script* command.

[image]

To change an hotkey for a specific window (let's say the **UV Editor**) you need to go in the *User Preferences>Keymap>Image>UV Editor* and modify/add your hotkey.

---

In your question you mention the "modeling tab", so you are speaking of the **Workspaces** in Blender. These are just different ways to arrange the different windows/panels in the UI, they are not different sections of the software: a 3D Viewport is the same in all workspaces, therefore all hotkeys will remain the same across different workspaces